# Possible "Transparent Film" effect in jQuery? I'm stumped

Tags: jquery, html, css, slideshow, carousel

OK, I'm in a real pickle here friends, and I need some help.

I have a website I am working on for a client of our company, but at the top of the page it involves a jQuery slideshow/infinite carousel mix that shows the CURRENT image in-between a 19-ish pixel white border on both sides and the other pieces of the carousel are supposed to be hidden under and behind a blue overlay.

When the client clicks the previous/next arrow (currently base text links that I'm going to re-position after I get this POS taken care of), the current image that is shown in the middle of the carousel on the page is supposed to slide to the left UNDER the white border and INTO the blue overlay (kind of like a transparent film effect, if you will).

Well, I'm STUMPED as to how I can get the image to slide under the border and overlay a color on top of it, ALL DYNAMICALLY without fading the entire image at once while moving to the left. It's supposed to be a super-smooth transition.

This is ULTIMATELY what it's SUPPOSED to look like:

http://www.powellcreative.com/clients/StansellHealth/images/help.png

This is what it looks like right now:

http://www.powellcreative.com/clients/StansellHealth/

Mind the crudeness of the current look and feel, it's still in the base development stages from the PSD, but this stumps me. Please help

Answer (score 0):

I created a very quick, non-functioning example to show you a technique you could use:

http://jsfiddle.net/gdgKQ/1/

Basically, you want to use two absolutely-positioned, partially transparent divs to create the film effect in the comp you're working from. If I have time and it'd be useful, I can add some JavaScript to show you the effect in action.

Comment: Let me fiddle with this in the code real quick and get back with you, however it looks like this is exactly what I was looking for. Hope it works like I'm wanting to. Thanks!

Comment: And if you do have time, if you wouldn't mind creating a working example in case I end up not being able to get it working, that would be really awesome too. I appreciate any help.

Comment: OK, check it out now on the live version:

http://www.powellcreative.com/clients/StansellHealth/

It works, but the color of the hidden image still bleeds through, I'm trying to make it to where the entire color is changed to the "film" color upon entering under that div

Comment: Ahhh. You're looking for a blending mode effect. Here's a blog post that offers some hacks: http://www.impressivewebs.com/image-tint-blend-css/

Blending modes are coming soon to CSS, but they're not really here, yet: https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/FXTF/rawfile/tip/compositing/index.html

Comment: BINGO, yeah that's it! 

Yeah I need a color-burn effect (based off that W3 doc). *sigh* that blog post you showed me definitely is a bit closer to what I want, but I need the colors completely burned with that blue.

Comment: Yeah - your only option is to time-machine into the future or to create duplicate images that are completely color-burned. I would encourage your designer to compromise on the normal (and currently achievable) semi-transparent effect.

Comment: HAHAHA, yeah, maybe I'll just crank up the ol' Flux Capacitor and get a move on. 

Thank you Nate so much, I'm eternally grateful for the help. Now to convene with the creative people lol